# Extracting xml attributes with go

Tags: xml, go, xml-parsing

How can I extract the 'id' attribute out of an element like `<vuln:cwe id="CWE-189" />`?  This is nested under `<entry>`.  My initial attempt was something like `xml:"entry>cwe,id,attr"`.

Answer (score 2):

Two approaches:

1/ keep getting the `Token()`, until the element has for name `cwe`.
Then a struct "CweXml" can extract the id attribute:

```
type CweXml struct {
    Id string `xml:"id,attr"`
}
```

2/ Or start from `entry`, but in that case you need a struct for it, which will contain `CweXml` struct.

```
type EntryXml struct {
    Cwe CweXml `xml:"cwe"`
}
```

In that case, you will find id in your `entryXml.Cwe.Id`.